# TCP buffer rate consumption

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I would like to modelize the rate at which a linux TCP receiver
consumes data in its buffer. I know it depends on how the application is
developed (if MSG_DONTWAIT is enabled etc...) but what would be the
most generic behavior ? what is the mean time between the arrival time
of packet in the buffer and the associated recv() return call ?

I would like to find that rate through TCP pacing at the sender : Like
I change the datarate of the TCP sender until the receiever window
remains stable, in which case the sending rate would be equal to the
receiver consumption rate. I would like to do TCP pacing in userspace
but I am afraid the kernel would prevent it (even with NAGLE disabled
etc...).

I am looking for any hints/papers that could provide me with this kind
of information

Best regards

Comment: The sending rate can never exceed the receiving rate anyway in TCP, because of receive window control. All you have to do is send the data and track how long it took. You need to set a large positive linger timeout so that the final close() is synchronous rather than asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Sender window is given by Minimum of(congestion window, receiver window). Usually the congestion window is slowly increases & stabilizes after a while. Faster the receiver application clears the kernel buffer faster the sender will push data.